# How can I randomly change the sign of numbers in a vector?

Tags: r, random, sign

I have a long vector of numbers that vary in the their sign (e.g.):

```
data <- c(1,-23,67,-21,10,32,64,-34,-6,10)
```

Working in R, how do I create a new vector that contains the same list of numbers, but give them a random sign (either positive or negative)? For each number, the probability of it being negative should be 0.5.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a bunch of options but

```r
sample(c(-1,1), size=length(data), replace=TRUE) * abs(data)
```

should work.  You could also multiply by `sign(runif(length(data))-0.5)` or `sign(runif(length(data),-1,1))` [either of which should be a little more efficient than `sample()`, although in this case it hardly matters].

Comment: Sure, I missed that part :=)

Comment: I like the `runif` part ie `data * sign(runif(data, -1, 1))`

Comment: You could simply multiply with ```abs(data)``` instead of just ```data```, this way the outcome will have a 50/50 plus/minus distribution... if the probability of a negative sign should be 0.5 and not the mere probability of changing a sign should be 0.5

Comment: Thanks everyone! This is correct, as I do not want a 50/50 distribution, I want the sign of each number to be determined by a coinflip.